# A place without hands

Tags: riddle, literature

Perhaps you have read of the story I tell
A tale of the darkness which cannot be felt
And the treasure that beds in the lidless lockbox
Of the dancing white horses with red gums for socks

In the roots of the mountain which outgrows the trees
I became acquainted with riddles much like these
When by my accounting, the fish, he held his breath
'til the cat made bony meal of his untimely death

But perhaps I bore you with these tales of witty quips
Traded with a hiker on his out and return trip
Without further ado, and a small break in the flow
Here is the final question, asked inversely so...

Where am I?

This riddle has been through the [sandbox](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5324/5297)

Comment: Previous comments deleted due to spoilers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's my guess:

> The speaker is Gollum.  ("Hiker on his out and return trip" would be Bilbo "there and back again").  The location is Mordor.  Gollum's interlocutor is Sauron.  The question, not asked inversely, is "where is the Ring?"  Which, from Sauron's point of view, is much the same as "where am I?"  This scene is referenced, but never depicted, in the books.

UPDATE: I finally figured out, duh, what is meant by "a place without hands".  Here's a revised guess:

> The speaker is the One Ring, and the place is Bilbo's pocket.

RE-UPDATE: I had assumed all the riddles were classics and well-known, besides being in the book.  My answer may be cheapened a little, because all these were known to me in advance.  Anyway here are the riddle explanations:

*The darkness which cannot be felt*

> Answer one of Gollum's riddles to Bilbo, which starts "it cannot be seen, cannot be felt".  The answer is "dark".

*The treasure in the lidless lockbox*

> Answer is "eggs", or as Gollum puts it, "eggses".  An alternate form of this riddle reads in part "no doors are there to this stronghold / yet thieves break in and steal the gold".

*dancing white horses with gums for socks*:

> Teeth.  One of Bilbo's riddles for Gollum.  "Thirty white horses upon a red hill..."  I've had this riddle in memory since childhood.

*The roots of the mountain which outgrows the trees*

> what has roots, goes up and up but never grows?  A mountain.  One of Gollum's riddles to Bilbo.

And one more:

> "No legs lay on one leg, two legs sat by on three legs, four legs got some."  I don't like to spoil this excellent riddle.

And then the final question, or the final 'riddle' Bilbo asks:

> "What have I got in my pocket?" One of Gollum's incorrect guesses was "hands", giving the question's title.

Comment: Really? You don't? What about said speaker's wrong guess?

Comment: Wow, I truly don't know what you're talking about.  Maybe you should answer this!

Comment: You've skipped the majority of the riddle, which has led you astray. You may be onto something with one of the parts though.

Comment: Your updated guess is the same as the one I was writing... but I just could not get some of the clues to line up. "Of the dancing white horses with red gums for socks" - I had no idea how I could link that answer to this clue for example.

Comment: This is the correct answer, although to accept it I think I'll need at least a couple of the other clues explained.

Comment: I agree that more explanation is needed before the answer should be accepted. Anyone who can't explain e.g. the dancing white horses and the treasure in the lidless box hasn't yet quite understood what's going on.

Comment: Muuuuch better now!